# Simple python code repeating an else statement, and i don't know why

Tags: python, function, if-statement, iteration

So i am new to python and have just started creating a basic program with a menu system that i will add to, to help display my progress and knowledge on python within one file, and to help make me more comfortable with multiple functions, functions calling function etc....

My program is repeating an else statement after inputting the sting that would make the if statement correct.

Take a look:

```
def menuReturn():
returnAns = input("Would you like to return to the menu? [y/n] ")

if returnAns.lower == "y":
    print("Returning you to the menu")
    print("")
    print("")
    print("")
    menu()

elif returnAns.lower == "n":
    print("Exiting...")

else:
    print("Please repeat the answer")
    menuReturn()

def askName():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    print(name + "? Thats a beautiful name!")
    menuReturn()

def menu(menuAnswer):
    if menuAnswer.lower == "askname":
        print("Good Choice!")
        askName()

    else:
        print("Please try again")
        menu(menuAnswer)

print("Welcome to the menu!")
print("")
print("Please enter a keyword from the following")
print("")                                                                       
#Add items here!
print("-askName")
menuAnswer = input("")
menu(menuAnswer)
```

I had to add some unnecessary indentations for me to post this question, so sorry about that

Please give a simple answer, as my programming 'lingo' is not at full capacity

Hope to hear from you soon,
John Fletcher

Answer (score 1):

`returnAns.lower` returns the string's built in lower function `<built-in method lower of str object at 0x*>`, and not the result of calling it. This is why the `else` appears to repeat, the `if` condition correctly fails. You want to call the lower function:

```
returnAns.lower() # returns the lowercase returnAns
```

Answer (score 0):

@TheoretiCAL is right. You want the function call to the string variable to be returnAns.lower() instead of returnAns.lower

Difference is that str.lower() returns a string with all lowercase characters, while str.lower is not a valid operator according to python string dosumentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html